# How to call std::string destructor explicitly without exposing the string via a using declaration?

Tags: c++, destructor, stdstring

I have this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

   std::string str = "Hi there!";
   std::cout << str << '\n';


   //using std::string;
   str.~string(); // error

}
```

The output:

```
g++ main.cxx -std=c++2a -o prog
main.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cxx:10:15: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token 10 |    str.~string();
```

- If I un-comment the line in main that contains the using declaration the program works fine but otherwise it fails to compile.
- I get that error so how can I call the destructor of `std::string` without exposing it through a `using declaration` or a `using directive`? Thank you!

Comment: string is an alias for basic_string< char > , so ~basic_string() will do.

Answer (score 7):

You should never call the destructor of a local variable. The destructor will be called at the end of the scope. You can introduce your own scope to make it happen early:

```
int main(){
   { 
       std::string str = "Hi there!";
       std::cout << str << '\n';
   } // str is destroyed
   std::cout << "no more str\n";
}
```

If you are allocating objects in a special way and really need to call the destructor, consider using `destroy_at`:

```
std::string* ptr = new(...) std::string("Hi there!");
std::destroy_at(ptr);
```

Comment: But in my real example I have a`std::string` as a member of a `union` that is a member of my `class` so I need to to call it to switch between member of the union.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Why not use a `std::variant` instead of a union?  Calling the destructor explicitly for anything other than `placement-new` is a huge code smell.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes I'm just calling it for a `placement new` as an exercise in the book. And I'll use `std::variant` when I'm done with the book. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @AtnNn, in your `placement-new` example, consider using `std::aligned_storage` instead of a manual `unsigned char[]` for the buffer, eg: `aligned_storage_t<sizeof(std::string), alignas(std::string)> mem;`. And `ptr` should be initialized from the return value of `new()`, not from `reinterpret_cast`'ing the buffer (unless you use `std::launder` in C++17), eg: `auto* ptr = new (&mem) std::string{"Hi there!"};`

Comment: Perhaps you can have a smart pointer that holds the string for you for as long as you need it to.